# Can't get druid running

Tags: fifo, druid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6nrt.png)
I have windows with linux subsystem and I am trying to run druid. I am getting a message CANNOT CREATE FIFO. What should I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue myself. Was trying to run through WSL Ubuntu. It seems that FIFO file can't be created over mounted drive i.e `/mnt/c/`.

Workaround for this, you'd have to copy the entire Druid installation folder over to any internal folder eg. `/usr/share/` and launch from there.